# Choose among activity only and fragment with hosting activity

Tags: android

Currently, when I click on a row of a list view, I would like to have a new screen for user to edit the detail of the selected row.

I realize I can merely implement the "detailed window" using `Activity`. However, in the future, I may / or may not need to support Tablet UI. Hence, I was wondering, in that case, should I implement all my logic and UI within a fragment, with another dedicated `FragmentActivity` to host the fragment?

I found there are good and bad

### Good

Easier code reusing and UI reusing, to cater different layout requirement, like new Tablet UI layout.

### Bad

Need to take care 2 classes (`FragmentActivity` and `Fragment`), instead of `Activity` only.

Personally, I'm more incline toward `FragmnetActivity` + `Fragment` design. But, I'm not sure whether there is any catch in my chosen design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it partially wrong - if all is done done right, your FragmentActivity is almost dummy host with interface to let fragments communicate their needs and all the code should stay in Fragment. And if you want the advice - go for fragments - it's much more flexible and not complicated.

Comment: Ya. I had done such implementation before, and I know FragmentActivity is pretty much a dummy hosting for Fragment.

Comment: So you know the answer then :)

Comment: Ya. Probably. But just that I don't know I had missed out any hidden catch.